# MySQL query. Can't manage to get it

Tags: mysql, database, relational

I have two tables inside a database. One stores unique userNames and a unique id and the other stores which users from the previous table are "friends": ex:

```
table users:
id   | username
---------------
100  |   aaa
200  |   bbb
300  |   ccc

table friends:
id | user  | friend
-------------------
1  | 100   | 200
2  | 300   | 100
3  | 300   | 200
```

Like in the above example, user 100 is friends with 300 and also 200. 
I'd like to display a list containing all of users 100 friends. Keep in mind he can appear in the "friends" table on both columns (user and friend). Can't figure out how the query should look like. Everything i try, it duplicates rows and whatnot.

I know it's trivial, but i'm new at this.

Comment: something like `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user=100 or friend=100`

Comment: It WIll be duplicated for the user 100 field friends is manytomany table. You will have to use group by  for user field and the group_concat on the friends field to get them in one row. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with no duplicate

```
SELECT distinct id FROM(
SELECT friend as id FROM friends
WHERE user = 100
UNION ALL
SELECT user as id FROM friends
WHERE friend = 100) ;
```

Comment: lol, i'm having difficulties converting your notations to mine ... :)

Comment: i'm not understanding what's mean "converting your notation to mine"!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select distinct u.id, u.username
  from Users u 
  inner join Friends f on u.id = f.id
  where f.friend = 100
UNION ALL
Select distinct u.id, u.username
  from Users u 
  inner join Friends f on u.id = f.id
  where f.user = 100
```

Or:

```
Select distinct u.id, u.username
  from Users u 
  inner join Friends f on u.id = f.id
  where f.user = 100 or f.friend = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

try below :

```
Select distinct u.id, u.username
from Users as u 
left join Friends as f on (u.id = f.user or u.id = f.friend)
where u.id=100
```